# Ruby on Rails - Why is Materialize.updateTextFields not a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I have a Ruby on Rails project that uses the `material-saas` gem. I recently noticed that text field animations have stopped working. More specifically, when a text field is active, the label does not move up on the page and whatever the user types in the input field writes over the label text and looks awful. [Here (https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/682)](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/682) is an example of the style issue I'm encountering. In addition to the label text not moving correctly, the form also has a file field that is not working. When a user selects a file to upload, the file name does not appear in the form, which is the intended behavior.

I recently ran `rake assets:clobber` and `rake assets:precompile` and I wonder if that has something to do with this issue.

I did some research and in the Material CSS docs they say:

> You can also call the function `Materialize.updateTextFields();` to
>   reinitialize all the Materialize labels on the page if you are
>   dynamically adding inputs.

I attempted this fix, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Materialize.updateTextFields is not a function` in my console when I load the page.

Here is my form view:

```
<%= render 'shared/header' %>
<div class="container">
<h3>New Photo of the Day</h3>
<div class="row">
<%= form_for @photo, multiple: true do |f| %>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.label :caption %>
    <%= f.text_area :caption, class: "materialize-textarea" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.label :date %>
  <%= f.date_field :date, class: "datepicker"%>

  <div class="file-field input-field">
    <div class="btn waves-effect waves-light yellow accent-4 white-text">
      <span>File</span>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>
    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
      <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field center-align">
    <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn-large waves-effect waves-light"  %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is my assets/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

Here is my assets/custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Materialize.updateTextFields();
});
```

This is all really strange because I know the form style animations were working. I did not change the code for my form. The only thing I can think of is the clobber / precompile command, which I needed to run to get some ui improvements up onto production.

Thanks for taking the time to look this one over and I appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a few issues to me:

Rails is magic, and it does something called "turbolinks." Basically, pages are dynamically replaced instead of actually changing pages. It makes your site faster, but doesn't always issue the same Javascript events.

You'll also need JQuery 2 (I've updated my answer after advice from Dmitry).

Change the first few lines of your application JS to:

```
//= require jquery2
//= require turbolinks
//= require materialize-sprockets
```

Secondly, I found a second bug that exists in the materialize library. Basically, it wouldn't define `updateTextFields()` until turbo links loaded a page. To fix this, I've [submitted a PR](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass/pull/145/commits/07f9fd4e488e6515554250ad206051aeccb8421a), but in the meantime, I would money-patch this by copy/pasting the method from the [source](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/materialize/forms.js) to your code (inside `$(document).ready`). Use something like this to let your code get updated once they fix the bug (pretty much a polyfill).

```
Materialize.updateTextFields = Materialize.updateTextFields || // code from forms.js
```

Comment: Bad advice. Use the jquery-turbolinks gem to trigger jquery events with turbolinks. The issue here is the use of jQuery 1, which completely breaks parts of Materialize.

Comment: The change would be to replace `//= require jquery` with `//= require jquery2`.

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev This is an awful solution, but it's the only one I can think of. While I wish it is bad advice, the library itself listens to the `turbolinks:load` event instead of the `ready` event, meaning it only defines `Materialize.updateTextFeilds` after navigation. Sadly, there are only three ways to fix this: 1 is to change the code itself to listen to both events (that requires a PR, which I sent). 2 is to trigger a `turbolinks:load` event yourself, but that might break other libraries, and 3 is to define the method yourself (what I suggested).

Comment: Again, the jquery-turbolinks gem [here](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) makes it "just work".

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Looking over the Readme, it would "just work" If it was using `$.ready()`, but the `materialize-sass` gem uses the turbo link on load event itself. That event only fires after a page change, but not on the initial load.

Comment: IME (for example [here](http://inventory.dk0.us)) it worked for me without performing any other configuration.

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Cool. I'm interested, so I looked at the source code of the gem (it's only 60 lines or so). Looks like it just sends the `turbolinks:ready` event, which probably triggers the `turbolinks:load` event.

Comment: I haven't really looked into the source of the gem, sorry about that

Comment: If you want to, let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143054/discussion-between-ben-aubin-and-dmitry-kudriavtsev).

Comment: I can't do that, I have a chat suspension.

Comment: Never mind - I have a Stack Exchange chat suspension, which does not apply to Stack Overflow chat.

Comment: jquery2 + turbolinks did it. I also got rid of the document ready function in my custom js. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery 1.x.

Try using jQuery 2.x or 3.x.

Source: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/4593

E: The way to do this in your setup would be to change the line `//= require jquery` to `//= require jquery2`.

Comment: This is very helpful documentation. Thanks for finding it.